# Gradle filter duplicate dependencies after they have been resolved

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have to develop a module against a live system that has a `lib` folder.
In order to get all the dependencies, I need to add a dependency on that folder.
Then I add my own new dependencies using the gradle way `compile ...`

The problem is the system already contains some of the libs I add as dependencies or that are resolved as transitive dependencies.

I would like to be able to though each dependency and if I find one with the same name in the lib folder, remove it, so I can use the one resolved from the maven repository.

Any idea where I can insert that code, or if it is possible ?

** I guess one other option would be to copy them and filter by hand into a new lib folder, I am wondering if I can make something automatic that may take into account future upgrades

Answer (score 0):

> I have to develop a module against a live system that has a lib folder.
>   The problem is the system already contains some of the libs I add as dependencies or that are resolved as transitive dependencies.

The best way to manage this case is to avoid the `lib` folder and just move all these libraries/dependencies in a **maven (private) repo**.

In this way gradle will manage all nested dependencies avoiding to duplicate libraries with different versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got something like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Unfortunately when you do this, the GAV (group, artifact, version) is not known to gradle. Each jar is simply a file without a GAV or any other metadata (eg transitive dependencies). None of these jars can participate in Gradle's dependency resolution.

If you want to put your jars in a local folder, I suggest you use the maven repository directory layout (eg `/someFolder/$groupIdWithSlashes/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version.$extension`)

You could then specify the local folder as a maven repository

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url uri('mavenRepo')
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'group1:artifact1:1.0'
    compile 'group2:artifact2:2.0'
}
```

Jars could then be stored as

```
mavenRepo/group1/artifact1/1.0/artifact1-1.0.jar
mavenRepo/group2/artifact2/2.0/artifact2-2.0.jar
```

Optionally, you might want to add poms with transitive dependencies etc at

```
mavenRepo/group1/artifact1/1.0/artifact1-1.0.pom
mavenRepo/group2/artifact2/2.0/artifact2-2.0.pom
```

More details on maven directory layout [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final)

Comment: The base problem is not where or how I store the dependencies. What I wanted to find is if I could run a script inside or after the dependency resolution phase that would allow me to remove some of the resolved dependencies, based on name, path or whatever is available.

Comment: It's related! Once you reference proper dependencies by GAV rather than a file you can then use gradle's dependency resolution to choose the right one when conflicts occur. Gradle will use dependency resolution when two or more dependencies are found with the same group and artifact

Comment: that is not possible in this case, some libs have other libs bundled inside, etc
I wanted to find if that "dirty" way was possible to implement.
I know the ideal case and the theory, but that doesn't simplify things here

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer because you don't want to do it properly, you want a hack

You could do something like this:

```
def libJars = fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
dependencies {
   compile 'foo:bar:1.0'
   compile project(':anotherProject')
   compile libJars
}
libJars.files.each { File libJar ->
    // assuming jars are named $module-$version.jar
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)-.+?\\.jar") 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(libJar.name)
    if (!matcher.matches()) throw new RuntimeException("${libJar.name} does not match ${pattern.pattern()}")
    String module = matcher.group(1)

    // exclude other dependencies with the same module as this "libJar"
    configurations.compile.exclude [module: module]
}
```